# Regular expressions in flex has error

Tags: c, regex, flex-lexer, identifier, lexical-analysis

I am new in flex and I want to design a scanner using flex.

At this step, I want to make regular expression to match with id, but here are some conditions:

1. underline can exist in id
2. you can use _ whenever you want, but if you are using them exactly 
   consequently it can be at most 2 underlines for example :

   a_b_c »»»» true

   a___b »»»» false

   123abv »»»» false
3. integers can't be at the beginning of an id
4. underline can't exist at the end of an id

The regular expression I have written for that is :

```
(\b(_{0,2}[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]*(_{0,2}[0-9A-Za-z]+)*)\b)
```

but now I have 2 questions:

1. Is the regular expression true? I have tested it in [rubular.com](http://rubular.com) and I think this is true but I'm not sure?
2. The other important problem is that when I write this in my flex file, Unfortunately no id is identified. But I can't why it is not recognized

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: The `_{0,2}` in the middle of your expression can be replaced by `__?` (the same as `_{1,2}`) to make it more efficient. Your outer parentheses are not doing anything expect making copies of the whole match so you can remove them. Is an id such as `_1b` allowed? Because currently your regex won't match it. If you want that too, you'll have to change your expression to something like `\b(_{0,2}[A-Za-z]|__?[0-9])[0-9A-Za-z]*(__?[0-9A-Za-z]+)*\b`. Alternatively you could change it to `\b([A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]*)?(__?[0-9A-Za-z]+)*\b`.

Comment: @CJDennis Thanks a lot for your explanation. Can you help me to make this in flex? it is not any matched id in flex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your `ID` regular expression.  You are using `\b` to match a word boundary, but Flex's regular expressions have no built-in support for matching word boundaries.  Other than that, your regular expression is sound.  I was able to get your code working using this modified version of yours: `_{0,2}[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]*(_{0,2}[0-9A-Za-z]+)*`.  (I just got rid of the `\b`'s, and some of the parentheses that bothered me).

Unfortunately, this causes a slight problem.  Say that you're lexing and run across something like `12_345`.  Flex will read `12`, assume that it found an `IC`, and then read `_`.  Finding no match, it will print that to stdout, then read `345` as another `IC`.

In order to avoid this issue (caused by Flex's lack of word boundaries), you could do one of two things:

- Create a rule at the end that matches any character (other than whitespace) and make it give an error.  This would stop Flex when it got to `_` in the example above.
- Create a rule at the end that matches any combination of letters, numbers, and underscores (`[_0-9A-Za-z]+`).  If it is matched, give an error.  This will cause Flex to return the entire token `12_345` as an error in the above example.

**One other problem:** The `ID` regular expression still won't match anything with underscores at the end of it.  This means your current regular expression isn't perfect, and you'll need to do some tweaking with it, but now you know not to use the `\b` symbol.  [Here](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html) is a reference on Flex's regular expression syntax so you can find other things to use/avoid.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great solution. It really helped me. I used the second one. it works correctly. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirement is:

1. Identifiers can use only alphanumeric characters and _
2. Identifiers cannot start with a number
3. Identifiers cannot end with an <kbd>_</kbd>
4. Identifiers cannot include more than two *consecutive* <kbd>_</kbd>

(When I first read your question, I thought the last requirement was that identifiers cannot include more than two <kbd>_</kbd>, but looking at the proposed regex, I think the version above is more accurate.)

Based on the above, you should be able to use the following two Flex patterns:

```
([[:alpha:]]|__?[[:alnum:]])(_?_?[[:alnum:]])*  { /* Handle an identifier */ }
[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]* { /* Error */ }
```

Breaking that down:

- `([[:alpha:]]|__?[[:alnum:]])` matches an alphabetic character or one or two <kbd>_</kbd> followed by an alphanumeric character.
- `(_?_?[[:alnum:]])*` matches a string of  and alphanumeric characters, with a maximum of two  before an alphanumeric character.

The second pattern will match anything which starts with an alphabetic character or  followed by any number of alphanumerics or . This will match all valid identifiers as well as the sequences which contain too many consecutive  or which end with . If both patterns match (that is, a valid identifier), the first one will win, so it will be correctly recognized. The second pattern will consume the entire erroneous identifier, allowing for easier error recovery.

The pattern in the OP doesn't work because flex treats `\b` as a backspace character (as in C). Flex does not implement word boundary assertions, but in a lexer you almost never need these; the pattern above can be used if necessary.